# Strange jquery .cycle plugin next/prev button behavior on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, button, slideshow, behavior

I am using jquery .cycle plugin code below for a photo slide with next/prev buttons. Everything works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE8. After I click one of the buttons and the slide changes to the next photo, both buttons move up about 10-15 pixels. And then they stay there until I hover over them again. When I click again, they move up again. I've been searching for an answer on google and forums with no luck. I tried different ways and even tested it with different versions of JQuery but I couldn't solve it. Anybody knows how to get that fixed? Thank you!

```
<head>

$(function(){
    $("#imgslide").cycle({next:"#next",
              prev:"#prev",
              pause:true, 
              timeout:0,
              cleartypeNoBg: true,
              after: onAfter,

              });
});

function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
            var index=opts.currSlide;
        $('#comment p:visible').hide();
            $('#comment p').eq(index).show();
        var caption = '' + (opts.currSlide + 1) + ' / ' + opts.slideCount;
        $('#caption').html(caption);
}

</head>

<body>

<div id="Container">
        <ul id="imgslide" style="height: 500px; list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0;">
            <li><img src="/images/portrait/image1.jpg" width="500px" height="500px"></li>
            <li><img src="/images/portrait/image2.jpg" width="500px" height="500px"></li>
            <li><img src="/images/portrait/image3.jpg" width="500px" height="500px"></li>
            <li><img src="/images/portrait/image4.jpg" width="500px" height="500px"></li>
            <li><img src="/images/portrait/image5.jpg" width="500px" height="500px"></li>
            <li><img src="/images/portrait/image6.jpg" width="500px" height="500px"></li>
            <li><img src="/images/portrait/image7.jpg" width="500px" height="500px"></li>
            <li><img src="/images/portrait/image8.jpg" width="500px" height="500px"></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="comment">
               <p>Title 1</p>
               <p>Title 2</p>
               <p>Title 3</p>
               <p>Title 4</p>
               <p>Title 5</p>
               <p>Title 6</p>
               <p>Title 7</p>
               <p>Title 8</p>
               </div>
        <a id="prev" style="cursor: pointer;" >Prev</a> |
        <a id="next" style="cursor: pointer; margin-left:2px">Next</a>
        <div style="display:inline; margin-left:10px" align="left" id="caption"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: It's not happening for me, http://jsfiddle.net/85nzq/20/

Comment: @KevinB That's based on the code you wrote yesterday for me on the forum..:) Strangely, I'm experiencing the issue on jsfiddle too. I think I'll ask a few people to test it for me to see if it is related my browser.

Comment: Are you running in compatibility mode? that would mean the issue is Ie7 not IE8. I didn't test IE7

Comment: No, I'm not running in compatibility mode, I have no idea what is causing this

Comment: You have an extra comma, make sure you remove it. `onAfter,`

Comment: I think I fixed it. The only way I could get it to work is by changing both jquery version to 1.5 and cycle plugin to jquery.cycle.all.latest.js . But one of my friends said on his IE he cannot see the slideshow but only the photos lined up after each other vertically. So I'm waiting to hear from him now after the version change. I also removed the comma, thank you!

Comment: Make sure that when testing after a change you close the browser and re-open it to ensure you aren't having a cache problem.

Comment: Yeah, I always do that. My friend just said it looks ok now on his browser too. Finally, I was about to go crazy! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Make sure you post it as an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know I had to do that, posting now. Thanks!...

Comment: Oops, I have to wait for 3 hours more to answer my own question as it seems. Because I have less than 10 reputations.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem;

1. I was using JQuery version 1.7.2, the latest one. Instead I changed it to version 1.5 using the following path;

   ```
   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js
   ```
2. As for Jquery Cycle plugin, I was using jquery.cycle.lite.js, which is the smaller version but I changed it to the full one that includes more features;

   ```
   http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js
   ```

These changes seem to fix the bug related to buttons that occurred with Internet Explorer IE8. And now the page works without problems in all browsers.